# masm pass floating point to function

Tags: winapi, assembly, floating-point, masm

I'm trying to draw a triangle on my screen, it works fine with calling winapi Polygon function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-polygon)

```
.data
xy POINT <350,50>,<350,70>,<370,70>

.code

...

INVOKE Polygon, hdc, offset xy, lengthof xy
```

while I check the document it says that POINT struct stores xy with LONG

```
typedef struct tagPOINT {
  LONG x;
  LONG y;
} POINT, *PPOINT;
```

but i think it is not possible to directly initialize the data like this

```
.data
xy POINT <350.5,50.5>,<350.5,70.5>,<370.5,70.5>
```

SO is it possible to call this function in masm with real4 or real8?

Comment: but [`Polygon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-polygon) take array of [`POINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-polygon) where must be `LONG` *x* and *y*. if you have float/double data - you need first convert it to `LONG` yourself

Comment: in my comprehension, there is only byte/word/dword and x,y are stored in dword, what do you mean LONG ?

Comment: `LONG` this is signed dword. 4 bytes. from masm view simply dword

Comment: does 'convert to long'  mean change double to 32bit foramt of sign/exponent/fraction, if so , can it directly store in dword instead of real4 and how could it know which type(normal 4 byte number and float point format) of format to read

Comment: mean use `cvttsd2si`